# VS Code cannot highlight mainly brackets or keywords

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am facing a problem where most of my keywords and brackets are turned into red and become impossible to highlight. The program also got very slow(freezes while scrolling through the code) and crashed while I was writing this post. I am having a problem with monokai theme which I always used. This issue does not appear with some other themes. For instance, with light(vs), dark(vs) and dark+ I don't have this issue whereas monokai, quiet light and red has this problem.

EDIT: And one more thing to mention, there is the 1-2 seconds lag of loading this reddy and annoying stuff while opening a new window with a new script. I think this thing, whatever it is, is loading after the theme is loaded.

Thanks in advance for any help to fix this problem.
[Here is the snippet of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9ton.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you are having an issue with one of your installed extensions. You could try to run VSCode from cmd/terminal using this command: `code --disable-extensions [path_to_file]` and see if you are still having these issues.

If running launching VSCode like this fixes your issue. you should open it again normally, and one by one, disable all of your extensions until you find the one that is causing the issue.

If this issue is caused by the monokai theme only I suggest you raise it as an issue with the developers of the theme.

[Picture outlining how to disable extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vowtm.png)

Comment: I have done what you said and found out that the problem is caused by C/C++ extension by Microsoft which is very strange. Thanks for the help. I have disabled the extension.

Comment: Glad you found the issue @OrkhanS. If my answer solved the problem please mark it as the solution :)